# Why don't I see the crashlogs in my analytics?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, analytics, appdynamics

I have integrated my app with AppD. In my dashboard I see lots of logs in regards to the location, transaction times, endpoints etc. Yet when I crash I don't the reports for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the simulator then the [Xcode debugger will catch the crash logs](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14855) and it won't be given to AppDynamics. So long story short you have get rid of Xcode interruptions.

You could either do:

- deploy and crash on the device
- just kill Xcode and then let it crash on the simulator. (I guess this is one of the reasons why simulator and Xcode are 2 different apps)

This logic should apply to all analytics e.g. Fabric/crashlytics.